# Javascript: Jumping into a specific part of an overflowing environment?

Tags: javascript

I have a  environment which overflows with text. This means the browser creates a little slider next to it, enabling the user to scroll the environment. My question is whether it is possible using some JS magic to make the browser "jump" to a specific part of the text; e.g. the user presses a button and the slider goes all the way down.

Comment: Try the `END` key... And yes, it can be done with JavaScript.

Comment: The point was the "specific part" (which can very well be in the middle); the end of text was only an example.

Comment: My comment is addressing the "all the way down" part of the question `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with straight HTML or javascript.

**HTML**

Link to click

```
<a href="#Test">Click Here</a>
```

Put this above where you want to jump

```
<div id="Test">Content to jump too</div>
```

**Javascript**

You can also do this using the [javascript scrollTo](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp) function

```
window.scrollTo(100,500);
```

Comment: Don't add empty anchor elements. Stick the id attribute on the element you actually want to link to.

Comment: I should have thought about it. Silly me. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple html to achieve this:

```
<a href="#foo">Click here to scroll down to section "foo"</a>
...
<a name="#foo">Section "foo"</a>
```

I included an example in the link below:
http://jsfiddle.net/C9Qj5/